# Array of 3 Dimensions to an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

Been stuck on this for a while.

```
let employees = [
 [
  ['firstName', 'Joe'],
  ['lastName', 'Blow'],
  ['age', 42],
  ['role', 'clerk']
 ],
 [
  ['firstName', 'Mary'],
  ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
  ['age', 36],
  ['role', 'manager']
 ]
]
```

To yield:

```
[
    {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
    {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}
]
```

How do transform this exactly? I have tried triple nested for loops, map/reduce, and shift(), but I can't get it work transform exactly

Answer (score 5):

Try this solution. Use **[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to iterate over first level items. In the `map` function iterate over nested array items via [**Array#forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and populate your object. Then from `map` return that object.

```js
let employees = [
 [
  ['firstName', 'Joe'],
  ['lastName', 'Blow'],
  ['age', 42],
  ['role', 'clerk']
 ],
 [
  ['firstName', 'Mary'],
  ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
  ['age', 36],
  ['role', 'manager']
 ]
];

const newEmp = employees.map(emp => {
   const obj = {};
   
   emp.forEach(([prop, value]) => obj[prop] = value);
   
   return obj;
});

console.log(newEmp);
```

Comment: Wow I never thought to use [0] or [1], as it said the properties could be unpredictable. Thanks so much

Comment: You could also change the `forEach` function to `([key, value]) => obj[key] = value`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use  [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop over the outside/main array.

Then you can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to change every array inside the main array to object.

```js
let employees = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'],
        ['lastName', 'Blow'],
        ['age', 42],
        ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'],
        ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
        ['age', 36],
        ['role', 'manager']
    ]
];

employees = employees.map(employee => employee.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item[0]] = item[1];
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(employees);
```

Comment: You could also change your inner function to `(acc, [key, value]) => { acc[key] = value; return acc; }`.

Comment: When I work with this, the first index returns as 'firstName', 'Joe' although the others return as lastName: 'Blow'

Comment: @AaditMShah Thanks for your note.

Comment: @jhazelton1 it works good for me. Also Did you try it in StackOverflow ? by clicking `Run code snippet` button.

Comment: @MohamedAbbas When I ran the code snippet, it worked in StackOverflow, so there must of been an error in my Atom text editor. Thanks

Comment: @jhazelton1 it's not about your editor. it's about the engine. Check your browser console.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would do:

```js
const employees = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'],
        ['lastName', 'Blow'],
        ['age', 42],
        ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'],
        ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
        ['age', 36],
        ['role', 'manager']
    ]
];

const entriesToObject = entries => {
    const object = {};
    for (const [key, value] of entries)
        object[key] = value;
    return object;
};

const result = employees.map(entriesToObject);

console.log(result);
```

Note that `result` can be converted back into `employees` by using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) like so:

```js
const result = [
    {
        firstName: 'Joe',
        lastName: 'Blow',
        age: 42,
        role: 'clerk'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Mary',
        lastName: 'Jenkins',
        age: 36,
        role: 'manager'
    }
];

const employees = result.map(Object.entries);

console.log(employees);
```

Hence, the `entriesToObject` function is quite useful as it's the [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of `Object.entries`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```js
let employees = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'],
        ['lastName', 'Blow'],
        ['age', 42],
        ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'],
        ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
        ['age', 36],
        ['role', 'manager']
    ]
];

translated = []

for(let dataGroup of employees) {
    person = {};

    for(let dataPoint of dataGroup) {
        person[dataPoint[0]] = dataPoint[1]
    }

    translated.push(person);
}

console.log(translated);
```

Comment: You could also change your inner `for` loop to `for (const [key, value] of dataGroup) person[key] = value;`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of

1. [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), for the complete new objects and the objects with just a key/value pair,
2. [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), for creating a new object out of single/value pair objects as parameters,
3. [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), for taking each element of an array as parameter,
4. [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), for getting the key and value out of an array and
5. [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), for getting a dynamic key into an object literal.

> ```
> employees.map(a => Object.assign(...a.map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))))
> //        ^^^                         ^^^                              1 Array#map
> //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                       2 Object.assign
> //                               ^^^                                   3 spread syntax
> //                                         ^^^^^^                      4 destructuring
> //                                                       ^^^           5 computed prop
> ```

```js
let employees = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']], [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]];
    result = employees.map(a => Object.assign(...a.map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Using `Object.assign` along with the spread operator is really smart.

Answer (score 0):

For Different Approach  do with [`Array#reduce`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjHmeOllvTVAhUDKo8KHTvXD8sQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Freduce&usg=AFQjCNHHMuqxJ882tP03jasOvA3-26VV9Q) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function

```js
let employees = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['lastName', 'Blow'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['role', 'clerk']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
]

var res = employees.reduce((a, b) => {
  var obj = {};
  b.forEach(function(i) {
    obj[i[0]] = i[1];
  })
  a.push(obj);
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `map`?

Comment: Already many people post with map function.That why I was adding a different approach .And what wrong with my answer.Why downvote to my answer? @AaditMShah

Comment: Using `reduce` over `map` unnecessarily complicates this problem. That being said, if you edit your answer and acknowledge that it's better to use `map` in this case then I'm willing to remove the downvote. I can't remove the downvote if you don't edit the answer.

Comment: complicated answers also one of the answer.It's  a learning platform people are getting all type of things And surely  I won't edit my answer.i'm not begging for vote

Comment: Sure, that's your prerogative. However, do note that I couldn't remove the downvote even if I wanted to because my vote is locked in. The only way I can remove it is if you edit your answer.

Comment: i was edited my answer. but shouldn't for your approach  @AaditMShah